# Microsoft Azure not honoring "Probe Interval"

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I have setup a load balanced port of two virtual machines with probe interval of around 60 seconds but the load balancer is still querying the port at the default interval of 15 seconds.

I tried setting the "Probe Interval" anywhere between 30 seconds to 90 seconds but the load balancer always probes it at interval of 15 seconds.

Is this a bug in the load balancer or am I missing something?

Probe Interval
[image]